# How to create an if statement for a relational database in ColdFusion?

Tags: database, coldfusion, cfif

How can I show a table row if a sub-task exists?

Database info:

- table1 tasks table
- table2 sub-task table

Some tasks have sub-tasks, so how do I create an if statement for the results table: if tasks table has a record in the sub-tasks table display the record below the task record.

```
<tr>
    <td> #taskName# <td>
</tr>
<cfif subtask exists display row>
    <tr>
         <td>#sub-taskName#</td>
    <tr>
</cfif>
```

Tried this:

```
<cfif taskID = sub-taskid>
   <tr>
      <td>#sub-taskName#</td>
   <tr>
</cfif>
```

Not sure if this is the best method and how to loop if more than 1 sub-tasks are present.

Comment: http://learncfinaweek.com/course/index - Would recommend reading up on some of the basics

Comment: The group attribute of cfoutput might help you with this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately you aren't anywhere near having functional code.  You can get better help on a specific issue here when your code is at least complete and sensible.

Comment: I'm afraid yer Q doesn't make much sense in the way that you are asking it (so: downvoted). You seem to be asking a CFML Q where the Q probably ought to be an SQL one. It's unclear whether you have even fetched the (sub)tasks data from the DB, or that's where yer having a problem. CFML doesn't do any data fetching, you need to run an SQL statement to do that, & then CFML can process the results. Seems to me like yer not "getting" that. The advice to work through LCFiaW is solid. I think yer understanding of how things work is not there yet, so is a bit early to be asking Qs on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of how to do this at bottom of this page : https://cfdocs.org/cfoutput

use similar to this for sql query

```
<cfquery name="taskQuery" datasource="mydatasource">
    SELECT taskId, taskName, subTaskName
    FROM tasks
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN subtasks ON tasks.taskId = subtask.taskId
    ORDER BY taskWeight, taskId, subTaskWeight, subTaskId
</cfquery>
```

OR use this object to demo code

```
<cfset taskQuery = queryNew("taskId,taskName,subTaskName","int,varchar,varchar",
    [ {taskId:1, taskName:"Task 1",subTaskName:"Subtask 1.1"}, 
      {taskId:1, taskName:"Task 1",subTaskName:"Subtask 1.2"}, 
      {taskId:2, taskName:"Task 2",subTaskName:"Subtask 2.1"} ])>
```

then output using

```
<table>
<cfoutput query="taskQuery" group="taskId">
    <tr><td><h2>#taskName#</h2></td></tr>
    
    <cfoutput>
        <tr><td>#subTaskName#</td></tr>
    </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
</table>
```

Comment: you can drop that into https://www.trycf.com/scratch-pad if you want to see it working

Comment: Your sql example needs an `order by` clause.

Comment: technically no, in practice yes... maybe the records are 'magically' already the right order... #lol